# Android osm map using geojson is very slow

Tags: android, geojson, osmdroid

I want to show geoJson objects in OSM map and to do this I'm using [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) (version 5.4) and [osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) (version 5.8) libraries. My activity is:

```
public class TempMapActivity extends Activity {

MapView map;

KmlDocument mKmlGeoJson;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    initMap();
}

private void initMap() {
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    map.setMinZoomLevel(18);
    map.setMaxZoomLevel(22);
    map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(2.9691, 101.7146));
    mapController.setZoom(18);
    setupGeoJson();
}


private void setupGeoJson() {

    String gJson = null;
    try {
        gJson = getGeoString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mKmlGeoJson = new KmlDocument();
    mKmlGeoJson.parseGeoJSON(gJson);
    FolderOverlay myOverLay = (FolderOverlay) mKmlGeoJson.mKmlRoot.
            buildOverlay(map, null, null, mKmlGeoJson);
    map.getOverlays().add(myOverLay);
    map.getController().setZoom(16);
    map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(2.9691, 101.7146));
    map.invalidate();
}


private String getGeoString() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_template);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

    String jsonString = writer.toString();
    return jsonString;
}
```

}

Objects from the geoJson is showing, but the map is working very slow when zooming out/in (when loading). When I switch off to load geoJson, the map is working fine. I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android doc [says](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#determining):

**Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11), the Android 2D rendering pipeline supports hardware acceleration, meaning that all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas use the GPU. Because of the increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, your app will consume more RAM.**

It turned out that I had forgotten to disable hardware acceleration in my activity where I used OSM Map with hundreds of GeoJson elements. Now I've disabled and the map works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your GeoJSON file contains numerous objects, taking a while to draw. If you can share it, we could advice. 
Is it slow with an emulator, or a physical device?

Comment: My GeoJson file is not so big (about 100 Feature items). The app runs on physical device. If I try to load that GeoJson file in your OSMBonusPackTuto or OSMNavigator project from github in such way that I'm loading in my project, map is working fine. But in my project map is very slow. Then I thought, maybe it's due to package name with bonuspack and for testing I created new project with applicationId(package name) "com.example.osmbonuspacktuto"and I wonder that map is working fast even if when loading GeoJson file.